# what is meant by: heterogeneous residual errors and homogeneous residual errors

Tags: terminology, residuals, heteroscedasticity

what is meant by: heterogeneous residual errors and homogeneous residual errors.
I am reading a paper that says the following:

```
    A compound symmetry model with heterogeneous
residual error (CSR) had the best fit, with a normal distribution of residuals and a mean of zero fitted to the trial
data for each year. The compound symmetry model with homogeneous residual error (CS) and a model extending
the CSR to higher dimensions (DIAGR) were the next best models in most cases
```

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323865203_Optimal_models_in_the_yield_analysis_of_new_flax_cultivars

I dont understand why CSR would be a better fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context heterogeneous residual errors must mean *errors with nonconstant variance*, often referred to as heteroskedasticity.  Homogeneous residual errors then is errors with constant variance, or homoskedastic errors.

Comment: THANKS Kjetil that helps !